# In Livescript, what does [Object] mean?

Tags: javascript, livescript

I have a LiveScript program which when asked to print out a data structure, instead prints "[Object]". LiveScript is normally very good at printing out objects or lists of differently typed objects, so what does this message indicate? Why can it not print out the object nor its type?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the same that it does in JavaScript. Look at this:

```
obj = {}
typeof obj // => "object"
obj.toString() // => "[object Object]"
```

This refers to the its type. When it is converted to a string, JS tries to stringify it! LiveScript does no more than compile to JavaScript. So on, that you see means that any side-effect code is transforming your object in a `string`. It would get easier to us help you with a piece of code, but this is perfectly deductible.